# Autocomplete using a datalist doesn't work properly with phx-change

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

When an option (e.g., banana) is selected from the autocomplete list populated by a `datalist`, the selected option (banana) is entered into the textbox as expected, but the autocomplete list is still displayed as shown in the attached image.
[image]

On the contrary, the list disappears as expected if the event is bound by `phx-submit` (rather than `phx-change`, `phx-keyup` or `phx-keydown`). Unfortunately, I can't use `phx-submit` because autocomplete list should be updated as the input is made.

It appears that when an option is selected, and LiveView finishes handling phx-change and updates the page, it re-activates the autocomplete menu. How can I avoid this and make the option list disappear when an option is selected?

```
<form phx-change="username_change2">

  <input  id="username2"
        type="text"
        name="username2"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        autofocus
        autocomplete="off"
        list="usernames"
        value ={@username}>
</form>

<datalist id="usernames">
  <%= for username <- (["apple","banana","cherry", "peach"]) do %>
    <option value= { username }><%= username %></option>
  <% end %>
</datalist>


def handle_event("username_change2", %{"username2" => kwd}, socket) do
  IO.inspect(kwd, label: "username changed2")
  socket1 = assign(socket, username1: kwd, username: kwd)

  {:noreply, socket1}
end
```